# VS2012 Publish Web Site dlls instead of cs-files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, publish

I have a simple ASP.NET project that I want to publish. I right-click on the project and press "Publish Web Site", however this generates all my .cs files to the selected folder, previously I've been getting dll files in my bin folder instead of the .cs files.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @TinkuRana , he is looking for the DLL files, not worried about having them.

Comment: @Tobias, check your app_data folder? I believe everything gets compiled into there...

Comment: I'm not getting any dlls in my app_data folder, instead i get all my .cs files in my folder that i publish to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem will be probably in the Publish setting. Please check if the option **Precompile during publishing** is selected. You can find the option here - Right click on the **Project** - **Publish Web Site** - section **Settings** - subsection **File Publish Options** - option **Precompile during publishing**.

Comment: I have "Precompiled during publishing" UNchecked and <compilation debug="false"> in web.config and STILL getting cs files instead of dll... I'm so confused!

Answer (score 2):

**To publish your website in one DLL:**

1. In Visual Studio, open a web application project.
2. Right click the project name in Solution Explorer, and then choose
   Publish.
3. Select the Settings tab.
4. Expand File Publish Options, and then select Precompile during publishing.
   Click Configure.

[image]

Refrence:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh475319(v=vs.110).aspx