# Issue with aspx.cs file, File not in back up

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have an `asp.net` website with out the file `aspx.cs`.
We have all other files but `aspx.cs` file is missing. Is it possible to host this in the server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [publish an ASP.NET site without pushing the .cs files to the web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723376/vs2012-publish-web-site-dlls-instead-of-cs-files).

You do however need the .cs files in order to compile the site when preparing it to be published.  If you have neither the .dll nor .cs files then you are out of luck.

Comment: When .cs is file not available on a hosted site then IIS uses the DLLs in the bin folder.